# making onchange work like onchange and not like onleave?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" onchange="OnDescChange();" />
```

but it does not act as i want. It runs the function when i leave the box, i would like to do it everytime the content of that inputfield changes, how do i do that?

(im trying to make a suggestionbox to the users input).

Ive also tried jquerys .change but it gives med the same result.

Comment: When you say "everytime the content... changes" are you looking to execute the function with each keystroke change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try onKeyUp or onKeyPress.

Comment: This will not catch copy-and-pase triggered by the mouse using the context menu!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `onkeypress` event:

```
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" onkeypress="OnDescChange();" />
```

Comment: thank you... i totally forgot that event! ty Sjoerd and thejh

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment using the onkeyup event handler

```
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" onkeyup="OnDescChange();" />
```

onkeydown or onkeypress could be used too, but the only problem to be aware of with that is that these event fires before the text in the input field has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'onKeyUp' or 'onKeyDown' events instead of 'onchange'

If you are using jquery you can use something like the following

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
   $("input").css("background-color","#D6D6FF");
});
```

Hope this helps.